# Java remove odd number from an mixed array

Tags: java, arrays

why isn't this code working? 
I'm supposed to write a function which removes the odd numbers from an array. here is my code but I don't know where it went wrong. It's giving me an error.

```
public class Test{
public static int [] removeOdd(int[] input){

    int c = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(input[i]%2==0){
            c++;
        }
    }
    int [] a = new int[c];
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(input[i]%2==0){
            a[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] mixedArray = {21, 33, 44, 66, 11, 1, 88, 45, 10, 9};
    for (int i = 0; i < mixedArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(mixedArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    int [] noOdd = Test.removeOdd(mixedArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOdd.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(noOdd[i] + " ");
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: "It's giving me an error" is not a specific description of the problem. Does it fail to compile? With what error? Is there an exception thrown at runtime? If so, what's the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry for that . It's actually giving me array index out of bound error.

Comment: What is the output of your code when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another index variable to access the items of `a` and not use `i`:

```
public static int [] removeOdd(int[] input){

    int c = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(input[i]%2==0){
            c++;
        }
    }
    int [] a = new int[c];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(input[i]%2==0){
            a[k] = input[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

The index variable `i` iterates through `input` and its values do not match and will exceed the permitted values of the indexes of `a` so I have used `k`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
int [] a = new int[c];
for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if(input[i]%2==0){
        a[i] = input[i];
    }
}
```

This loop will iterate through the whole `input` array, and try to insert just the even ones into `a`, but `a` is smaller than `input`, because you allocated space equal to the amount of just the even numbers in `input`.

In your test case, your `a` will have size 4, but will try to access the position 6, giving you an out of bound exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to insert at `a[i]` which you could visualise like this:

```
index:  0 1 2 3 4

input: [1 2 3 4 5]
a:     [  2   4  ]
```

However, your `a` array is smaller than your input array, because you have reduced the size to account for the lack of odd numbers. You actually want to do this:

```
index: 0 1 2 3 4

input [1 2 3 4 5]
a     [2 4]
```

Notice how the index of both even numbers has changed. You were trying to keep it the same.

One way to solve this would be to keep a separate counter variable which tracks where you're up when inserting into `a`.

```
int[] a = new int[c];
int sizeOfA = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        a[sizeOfA] = input[i];
        sizeOfA++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the method `removeOdd` using **Streams**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static int[] removeOdd(int[] input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] mixedArray = { 21, 33, 44, 66, 11, 1, 88, 45, 10, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < mixedArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(mixedArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int[] noOdd = Test.removeOdd(mixedArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < noOdd.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(noOdd[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```